# Updating multiple attributes across different tables based on conditions in AWS DynamoDB Using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to update multiple tables based on condition. for example I have two tables, table1 and table2
Condition is for example if repID is 5000 and ReleaseDate is set to string "NaT" then update it with current date.
Same for table2 but only diffrence is in table2 instead of ReleaseDate I have Enddate.

repID is not a partition Key or Sort key in both tables.

Code I tried is:

```
def update_dynamo_agent_release(table_name, repID, enddate, attribute):
    table_name = os.environ['DYNAMO_PREFIX']+table_name
    parsed_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(enddate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    formatted_date = parsed_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
    update_expr = f"SET {attribute} = :end_date"
    condition_exp = f"custom_repid = :repID AND {attribute} = :enddate"
    parameter_values = {
        'repID': str(reporting_agent_id),
        'enddate': str(formatted_date)
    }
    expression_attributes = {
        'custom_repid': 'repID'
    }
    
    dynamodb.update_item(
        TableName = table_name,
        Key={'custom_repid': {'N': 'repID'}},
        UpdateExpression = update_expr,
        ConditionExpression = condition_exp,
        ExpressionAttributeValues = parameter_values,
        ExpressionAttributeNames = expression_attributes
        )

update_dynamo_agent_release(table1, 5000, "2023-09-08", "ReleasDate")
update_dynamo_agent_release(table2, 5000, "2023-09-08", "EndDate")
```

But its not working.
giving lot of error like this

```
Parameter validation failed:\\\\nInvalid type for parameter ExpressionAttributeValues.repid, value: 12945, type: <class 'int'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>\\\")\"}"
```

Is there any better way to do it. repID can be any ID present in table whose releasedate/enddate is set to "NaT"

Comment: So many questions. To begin, what are the partition and sort key for your tables?

Comment: @LeeHannigan partition key is createtimestamp, and sort key is entryID, but the issue is I can't go with both of them as from process I receive repID and enddate value that needs to be updated, that's why instead of partition/sort key I need to find the required item based on repID and enddate = "NaT".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, here is my answer.

You cannot update an item without knowing it's keys. You will first either need to Scan the entire table to get the keys of the item you wish to update, or if it's a frequent task, create an index on the values that you have and obtain the keys from the index.

But the bottom line is you need the base tables keys to update the item.